# CentOS7 repository- is there such a thing?

Tags: linux, centos, repository, cobbler

I have found a CentOS7 EPEL repository here:

```
http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/7/x86_64/
```

but I was wondering if there is such a thing as just a Centos7 repository (i.e. not the EPEL one)?

The reason I ask is I'm looking through a cobbler servers listed repositories, and for the previous version of Centos (6.5) it states it holds both a "Centos6.5-EPEL" repository AND a "CentOS 6.5" repository. Yet when I google to try and find the location a purely Centos repository, I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the CentOS 7/7.1/7.2 Repos at http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.2.1511/.